# Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features while using paypal sandbox

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using PayPal sandbox for the payment gateway, this is first time I'm trying to inbuild payment gateway to my site.

I simply used the form tag as follows

```
<form target="paypal" method="post" action="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
```

With other details, I tried both http and https here, but it is sending me to a page where it ask me to login to PayPal with following message:

> Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.

I don't have an idea what to do now. Am I doing something wrong in code? Please direct me what exactly the procedure to inbuild PayPal service to site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PayPal sandbox works as follows.  First, you create an overall "Sandbox Developer Account".  You would usually do this using your own email address.

Then, within that "Sandbox Developer Account" you create "Test Accounts".  PayPal will auto-generate email addresses for these accounts, and they wind up being rather long and incomprehensible. These are the accounts that will actually buy and sell things using the PayPal Sandbox.

In order to view *any* page on the PayPal Sandbox you need to be logged in using the parent "Sandbox Developer Account".  You will then be allowed to send carts to the Sandbox, or login to the Sandbox using one of the Test Accounts.

You login to your "Sandbox Developer Account" by going to developer.kiva.org.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this: the problem is that you're redirecting to `http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`. This should be `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr`