# PayPal Sandbox Error: Cookies are blocked

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-sandbox

I was working with paypal sandbox account. It was working fine. But, now it shows the following error.

[image: PayPal Error]

The cookies are enabled. I tried using different browser and a different computer. Still I'm getting the same error. I tried clearing the cookies and cache. But it didn't work. Any solution?

Comment: Sorry for adding comment so late. I contacted PayPal and they said they were experiencing some issues. And, the problem was solved automatically and almost very soon

Answer (score 3):

> Please turn on cookies to check out

This is a Paypal's issue which affects Express Checkout on the PayPal Sandbox. Paypal announced that there is no alternative workaround at the moment.

**Reference:** https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=6109

Answer (score 2):

This works for me: [Paypal Sandbox Frustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688287/paypal-sandbox-frustration)

To simplify:

1. Login first your developer's account here: http://developer.paypal.com
2. Open another tab and login your developer's merchant account here: https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com/apiAccess.do?subaction=api
3. Open another tab again and do your express checkout process.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem but after login here: https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com/apiAccess.do?subaction=api
I'm having error: "This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address"

Comment: This solution does not work for me and I also have the same issue - "cookies are turned off"

Comment: @komluk you should create a merchant and buyer sandbox account on your developer's dashboard under accounts' tab.

Answer (score 0):

To add an experience : In the beginning I had serious SSL issues when connecting to sandbox for a SetExpressCheckout:
The type of error was javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Error

To bypass this error (never happened before), i added the api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com certificate to my java truststore.

After that, the setCheckout responded correctly with a valid token, but I run into the 'cookie are turned off' problem, for almost 8 hours now. None of my websites is working with the sandbox environment.

I think nothing can be done until PayPal make things clearer with some announcement.