# Cookies are turned off Secure Payments PayPal requires cookies to be turned on for many of its features.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, spree-paypal-express

I am trying to integrate Paypal express into my spree e-commerce application
I proceed as follow:
in Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree_paypal_express', github: 'spree-contrib/better_spree_paypal_express', branch: '2-4-stable'
```

and I run this command:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rails g spree_paypal_express:install
```

I got the paypall payment method in the backend configuration panel and I add my API credentials data (username, password and signature)
I have the payPall button added to the other payment method but when i click it I got this error:

```
Please turn on cookies to check out
```

and cookies are activated in my chrome browser so why I got this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you and the solution here helped me out: 
[PayPal Sandbox Error: Cookies are blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712783/paypal-sandbox-error-cookies-are-blocked)

To simplify:

1. Login first your developer's account here:
   http://developer.paypal.com
2. Open another tab and login your developer's merchant account here:
       https://paypalmanager.sandbox.paypal.com/apiAccess.do?subaction=api
3. Open another tab again and do your express checkout process.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal changed it's Privacy policy last year and is using unsecured cookies (JSESSIONS) Your session information could be stolen in transit by hackers, very worrying and something Paypal is failing miserably to address- be wary. This is why Sandbox rightly blocks them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.